# Ubuntu desktop disk image (16.04.4 -desktop- amd64.iso) could not be opened

Tags: system-installation

After installing Ubuntu, the desktop disk image (16.04.4 -desktop- amd64.iso) could not be opened. I get the reason

> image not recognized

on Apple Mac Air. How do I resolve this, please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is out of scope of Ask Ubuntu. Please see Ask Different.

Comment: @ubashu I think this question is on topic, since it's basically about installing Ubuntu

Comment: @Zanna Probably the right thing would be to close as a duplicate [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86/how-do-i-create-an-ubuntu-live-usb-using-a-mac), but it's also kinda unclear imo (XY-problem?). Why does OP want open the iso in the first place?

Comment: Despite of the detailed answer written by @Chexier, I want to draw your attention also to these topics: [Methods to try out new OS releases without committing to it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1012717/566421) and [How To Install Ubuntu on VirtualBox (Mac)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNixOS6mHlU).

Answer (score 5):

I think you didn't install Ubuntu, you just downloaded the ISO. You don't usually open .iso files, you need to burn them to an USB drive. To do this, I recommend Etcher. It's compatible with Mac OS X (which you are probably using). You'll need a 2 GB USB Drive to put the Ubuntu ISO on it, but I would use an 4GB one, for extra space.

**1. Download [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) and burn the ISO to the Flash Drive**

Download Etcher and open it. You'll be greeted with it's GUI. Just click on "Select Image" button and browse your file system and click on the ISO you want to burn (Ubuntu).

Next, Select the Drive where you want to burn it. It should be selected as your USB, if not, plug in the USB Device where you want to burn it. **(This will erase ALL data on the drive, so backup your data if you have any!)**

Now, just click the "Flash!" button and wait. After some minutes it should show "Flash complete!" and you can close the program.

**2. Boot in to the USB drive**

Reboot your machine, and hold Alt during the boot process, right after hearing the Mac startup sound. It now should show "EFI Boot" (it should be the option to the most right) Now you just press "Enter" at the screen that shows you GRUB.

**3. Install Ubuntu**

Now you just click "Install Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS" icon on the desktop. Follow the on-screen instructions. There is a step that asks you where to install Ubuntu. You can dual boot OS X or replace it entirely, as it shows on the screen. If you choose to replace it, **ALL** your data will be gone on your disk, which will leave you only with Ubuntu installed. If you are going to do this, **Backup your data on OS X, and restore it later!**

**4. Enjoy!**

Now enjoy your newly installed system. I also wanted to say that, if you want to install Proprietary NVIDIA drivers, you should try [this article.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264247/proprietary-nvidia-drivers-with-efi-on-mac-to-prevent-overheating)(if you use EFI, which you probably use). If you don't do this workaround, you're probably getting a black screen after X starts. In my case it worked. **But do this at your risk!**

Comment: I just want to attach this as an additional reference: [Create a bootable USB Stick on macOS](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0) on Ubuntu Tutorials.